# add_header X-Frame-Options DENY; in nginx conf is not working, i can still see the iframe in our application

Tags: angular, nginx, iframe, x-frame-options, clickjacking

## `add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;` seems not working for us.

we are intended to display one of our hosted page as an iframe for PCI related issues, and we are succeded in that but to avoid **clickjacking**, we were recommended to use `x-frame-options DENY` but we can't do that since we want our users to use the frame we developed, so the solution might be using `x-frame-options ALLOW FROM uri`.

we are trying `add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;` to see if our application is restricting the iframe in the first place but the iframe is still visible. we verified several times if the add header might be in wrong place in the nginx conf, but it is not.

**P.S.** the below image is for ref but we can still see the angular application rendering the frame succesfully :(

[image: DENY]

Comment: why is `content-type` — `text/plain`?!

Comment: I pasted that image cause we see that in the every file that is rendered in the application. @cnst

Comment: When testing, are you embedding an `iframe` from another domain?

Comment: no the iframe is from the same domain [parent(somename.mylab.io) and child as in iframe(othername.mylab.io)]

Comment: can you confirm that the `x-frame-options` header is set on the response to the `index.html` request and not some asset or API call

Comment: in that case, allow from uri is not working

Answer (score 1):

Add below code under **location** block in **nginx.conf**

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;
```

Example

```
 location / {
        expires -1;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0';
        add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;
        root  <root directory>;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an old browser because it works in Chrome 68. You can inspect the Javascript error and the HTTP headers with <kbd>F12</kbd>.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: No, I tried using chrome and firefox latest versions. @youkouleley

Comment: can you confirm you don't see facebook page when you run my snippet?

Comment: my friend, I want to see the same behavior in my application. I tried the same example ages ago. the question is why is it not working in my application !!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your hosted page is in URI1 and your hosting page is in URI2

What's the response headers when you send a GET request to get URI1 directly?

I think that you add the 'x-frame-option' to the response for URI2 instead of URI1